# Wordpress - Filter posts by multiple meta keys with same value

Tags: php, wordpress

**LOOP:**

```
<?php
$meta[] = array(
    'key' => 'myfield1111',
    'value' => 'myvalue', //same value, it exists in this field
    'compare' => 'LIKE'
);
$meta[] = array(
    'key' => 'myfield2222',
    'value' => 'myvalue', //same value, id doesn't exists in this filed
    'compare' => 'LIKE'
);

$loop = new WP_Query(
    array(
        'post_type' => 'myposttype',
        'posts_per_page' => 24,
        'paged' => $paged,
        'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        $meta
    ),
));
?>
```

Results of this is empty query (no posts returned), even if value `myvalue` exits in key `myfield1111`. Its not logical to me, since I used `OR` relation it meta query.

Why is this happening, and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

```
<?php
$querystr = "
    SELECT $wpdb->posts.* 
    FROM $wpdb->posts, $wpdb->postmeta
    WHERE $wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->postmeta.post_id 
    AND ($wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = 'myfield1111' AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value LIKE '%myvalue%')
    OR ($wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = 'myfield2222' AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value LIKE '%myvalue%')
    AND $wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish' 
    AND $wpdb->posts.post_type = 'myposttype'
    AND $wpdb->posts.post_date < NOW()
    ORDER BY $wpdb->posts.post_date DESC
";

$pageposts = $wpdb->get_results($querystr, OBJECT);              
?>
```